# How to solve "JSX element implicitly has type 'any' " error?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

Even though I've installed & referenced the Typings library 'react' like this

`/// <reference path="../../../typings/browser.d.ts" />`

I'm still getting the error below:
[image]

Is there another Typings library I should be installing as well?

Answer (score 393):

I solved this issue by reloading VSCode.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> -***or***-
<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

Then type: `Developer: Reload Window`

Comment: I had this issue after upgrading from react-dom 16.x to 17. Reloading the window fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Restarting TypeScript Language Server would probably be enough: `CMD`+`P` > `Typescript: Restart TS Server` (type in `rets`)

Comment: it is ctrl+shift+P

Comment: For me it was `cmd` + `shift` + `p` It looks like `cmd` + `p` without shift brings up file search for me

Comment: In VSCode the `>` character denotes a command. Alternatively, yes, you can use `Ctrl + Shift + p` and then type in `Developer: Reload Window`.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I should've tried this before Googling.

Comment: Or just `Crtl` +`R` ?

Comment: Also closing and reopening fixes this.

Comment: I've changed the answer to Ctrl+Shift+P because people were forgetting to use `>` after doing Ctrl+P.

Comment: It would be good to understand what the underlying issue is.  Does anyone understand what that was?

Comment: I resolved this issue by deleting the project repository and cloning the repository again and running `npm install` command then start the project and it started working for me.

Comment: if you are using typescript, this will not help, you need to install the @types/react to fix this

Answer (score 135):

I resolved this issue by installing the react type definition.

Try to run:
`npm install --dev @types/react`
or
`yarn add --dev @types/react`

Comment: For npm, `npm install --dev @types/react` is worked

Comment: If you are using yarn with Typescript and do have node_modules, add Typescript support for your editor using Yarn. Run: `yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode`. VSCode will prompt you to allow it.

Comment: Do not forget to install `Node` first

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your solution! Your help is greatly appreciated and has made a significant difference for those who were facing the same issue. Your contribution to the community is valuable and your generosity in sharing your knowledge is commendable. Thanks again for your support! it worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me,Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

There are two versions of React available in Typings. I've seen this issue with `typings install react` and using `noImplicitAny`.

I resolved this by installing the global version: `typings install dt~react --global`[image: typings search react results]

Comment: I really wish they'd consolidate their libraries. Having to deal with global \ ambient \ main conflicts in multiple places is an endless hassle for our team :(

Comment: I totally agree. I wish more vendors would publish their typings embedded in their libraries (like ImmutableJS)

Answer (score 24):

This is happening because your Typescript IntelliSense is not working properly.

1: To fix this just close and reopen your code editor and everything works like a charm!

2: There is another quick turnaround for this issue is just press
(Windows: `ctrl + shift + p`) or (Mac: `cmd + shift + p`) then search `Typescript:Restart TS server` hit enter and done.

Comment: Tried this on Windows and works like a charm, thanks

Answer (score 19):

Try run this:

```
1. npm i @types/react --save-dev

2. npm i @types/react-dom --save-dev
```

Works for me.

Comment: Worked for me too! It's also proposed by VS Code when you hover over the marked text.

Answer (score 6):

Run:

```
npm i -D @types/react @types/react-dom
```

Then make sure you have the following in your `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  }
}
```

This should ideally solve the problem, if not, try reloading the window.

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

You can install @types/react and @types/react-dom and then restart the window.

**Step 1.** npm i @types/react --save-dev

**Step 2.** npm i @types/react-dom --save-dev

**Step 3:** Run **Ctrl+Shift+P** -or- **⌘+shift+P**

Then type: `Developer: Reload Window` and press enter.

[image]

Comment: I was playing with a React (TypeScript + SWC) app generated with vite and it didn't install react-dom. Step #2 helped here.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Vue 2 with "Volar" (Vue 3), disable it for the workspace.

Answer (score 3):

Need to add vscode support if you are using yarn as your package manager.

Run the code below in your project's terminal:

`yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode`

See https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/editor-sdks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks! works without the fullstop at the end `yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode`

Comment: Link to docs: https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/editor-sdks

Answer (score 2):

For people getting this error in Deno or while getting started with Fresh framework a fiw for me was to disable the Deno extension in VS Code

Answer (score 2):

Just Reload the IDE/Code Editor. It will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Put this configuration in the tsconfig.json file so that the ts server does not recognize that type of errors

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "build/dist",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "build",
        "scripts",
        "acceptance-tests",
        "webpack",
        "jest",
        "src/setupTests.ts"
    ],
    "types": [
        "typePatches"
    ]
}
```

Comment: must be  
"jsx": "react-jsx"

Comment: React [docs](https://react.dev/learn/typescript) state that `"jsx": "preserve"` should suffice for most applications. Using this setting eliminated a couple other false errors for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and after reading the other solutions I looked at my `tsconfig.json` and apparently it (vs-code) complained about a minor error in my config and when I corrected that, it went away.

So main take away: ***Check that you have no errors in the tsconfig***

**Note**
I am not sure the error was relevant, but vs-code complained that `checkJs` was defined (no set to false) when my `allowJs` was set to false. So basically my solution was to set both `allowJs` and `checkJs` to false:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "allowJs": false,
    "checkJs": false,
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Which just [disables type checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#checkJs) altogether for .js files.

Answer (score 1):

When this happened to me, the cause was running the app inside a docker image, but not having vscode point to that docker image. I ran `npm run install` to install the `node_modules` directory where vscode can see it. After that, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, updated the `tsconfig.json` into the below code and restarted the server worked for me.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2016",
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "allowJs": false,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "keyofStringsOnly": true,
    "lib": ["es2015", "es2017", "dom"],
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also needed to add `npm i @types/react-dom --save-dev` to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

`ctrl + shift + p` will Reload the **window**.

If using **TypeScript** using `ctrl + shift + p` will Reload **TS Server**

Answer (score 0):

If you came here after updating vs code. Then you need to change the version of the typescript used in the settings.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTAjx.png)

Comment: I think that this is more a lack of the react library package. the typescript error would be correct, but it's missing information. @types/react covers this and adds the types typescript expects.

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem in a Next.js project (v13.4.12).

After creating the project, this is what's inside package.json

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "01-firsts-steps",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "20.4.5",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "eslint": "8.46.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.12",
    "next": "13.4.12",
    "postcss": "8.4.27",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3",
    "typescript": "5.1.6",
    "valibot": "^0.8.0"
  }
}
```

In page.tsx i got the warning:

**JSX Element implicitly has any type 'any' because no interface 'JSX.IntrinsicElements' exists**

To solve it, what I did was uninstall the packages:
**@types/react and @types/react-dom**, using:

```
npm uninstall @types/react @types/react-dom
```

Finally, reinstall the packages:

```
npm install @types/react @types/react-dom
```

And that's it !

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm install` this fixed issue for me

Answer (score -1):

### Delete `node_modules` and run `npm install`

I could not pinpoint a specific issue, and doing this fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score -9):

From the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html), React must have a capital letter. The code in the question clearly does not.

Comment: Thought it was worth letting you know why you (or, future readers) got downvoted: only React components must use a capital letter, not html elements